# Android - getevent command logging in thread

Tags: android, multithreading, shell, command

```
@Override
public void run() {
        try {
            exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getevent | grep event1");
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(
                    exec.getInputStream());
            String s;

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
            Log.i("br.readLine", " = " + br.readLine());
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.i("s2", " " + s);
            }
    //        is.close();
    //        exec.destroy();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("thread ioexception", " " + e.getCause());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I tried logging the results of the command to getevent in thread.

But put the results of the command in the buffer, the buffer is empty(null).

Perhaps as soon as this command is executed, it seems that ends without receiving any input.

While maintaining thread I want to continue to be run getevent command.

How this can be done? any idea?

**Edit**
getErrorStream()

```
getevent [-t] [-n] [-s switchmask] [-S] [-v [mask]] [-d] [-p] [-i] [-l] [-q] [-c count] [-r] [device]
                                                                                                    -t: show time stamps
                                                                                                    -n: don't print newlines
                                                                                                    -s: print switch states for given bits
                                                                                                    -S: print all switch states
                                                                                                    -v: verbosity mask (errs=1, dev=2, name=4, info=8, vers=16, pos. events=32, props=64)
                                                                                                    -d: show HID descriptor, if available
                                                                                                    -p: show possible events (errs, dev, name, pos. events)
                                                                                                    -i: show all device info and possible events
                                                                                                    -l: label event types and names in plain text
                                                                                                    -q: quiet (clear verbosity mask)
                                                                                                    -c: print given number of events then exit
                                                                                                    -r: print rate events are received
```

GetErrorStream comes out as the result of a manual getevent.

If the instruction is to operate normally, it would not have been any log (the other normal commands actually did. Ex) ls  )

I think getevent command seems to have caused various problems since the **CALLBACK** method.

Comment: Please remove the "grep" command when using "getErrorStream()". Just call "getevent" to see what is going wrong there.

Comment: According to the word does not include any error only when I run the command "getevent". But it harden application without any response.

Comment: I 've run commands as you said, but it harden..  But it seems to be getting closer to resolution. :)

Comment: What is your output after running /system/bin/sh -c "getevent | grep event1"?

Comment: it just harden. without any error message. If the problem of cross-platform, it should not operate any other instructions. (I think)

Comment: But you are using getInputSteam() again right?

Comment: both getErrorStream() and getInputStream() are checked using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I think now I got your problem. The pipe behavior is not cross-platform, as it is a functionality of the executed shell. Thats why it is not working as you expect in java. Try to use a script like the following to spawn a new shell which implements the pipe function as you expect.

```
String[] cmd = {
    "/system/bin/sh",
    "-c",
    "getevent | grep event1"
};
```

I'll keep the rest of the answer, as it could help somebody.

I think you are executing `getevent | grep event1` without the correct permissions. At least you need to be `root` user or in `input` group.

**Edit**: I still think you do not have the correct permissions. Of course, for running `getevent` no special permissions are necessary, as it can be executed by everyone. But keep in mind, that `getevent` reads `/dev/input/*`, which has the following permissions:

```
crw-rw---- root     input     13,  64 2016-01-24 21:34 event1
```

Try to make sure your application is really allowed to read `event1`.
You should also try to use `getErrorStream()` instead of `getInputStream()` to see what is going wrong.

Regarding the second part of your question, I am not sure I understand it correctly. You want to execute the command periodically in the same thread right? (I did not, see edit below.)

Then you can simply run your code in a `while(1)` loop and sleep as long as you want. A bit more advanced would be to use a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and a [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

If you want to control every loop from outside your Thread you can simply use `Object.wait()` and `Object.notify()`. Another, also more advanced, possibility is to use [Thread pools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html). The interesting one for you could be the [SingleThreadExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor-int-).

**Edit:** As I thought, I did not understood you correctly. However, I'll keep the second part of my answer, maybe it helps someone else.

For your use case your code should work correctly. I think it does return immediately because an error is happening. As described above, try to use `getErrorStream()` to see what is actually happening.

Comment: Device is rooted. Applications also have root privileges.

"Getevent | grep event1"

This command is to monitor the event1 occurring within the device.

If the adb shell to run commands on the monitors event1 until you enter the ctrl + z.

What I want to watch on as adb shell event1,
In my application I want to watch event1. until the end of the thread.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, please see edited answer above. Please try using getErrorStream().

Comment: OMG. It was a simple mistake. The command was terminated at the same time as the thread begins! Fortunately solved as well getErrorStream ()   Thank you very much nilo